# my sprite is undeclared?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

i declared the sprite in my .h but how do i call the sprite from the node i declared it in so that i don't get the error that it is undeclared.

```
@interface MyNode : CCNode{
CCSprite *Bsprite1, *Tsprite1, *currentSprite;  
Boolean isChanging;

}
@end

currentSprite = [c1array objectAtIndex:i];
//error 'currentSprite' undeclared.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the currentSprite iVar from within the same class?

Comment: @Michael, i do not know how to access it from the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working had to create a pointer to it MyNode *currentSprite

Answer (score 0):

try separate the CCSprite declarations..

```
CCSprite* Bsprite1;
CCSprite* Tsprite1;
CCSprite* currentSprite;
```

I hope your `currentSprite = [c1array objectAtIndex:i];` is at your .m..

Comment: i tried the separate declarations and it made no difference and yes currentSprite = [c1array objectAtIndex:i]; is in my .m file

Comment: i tried that and it still does not work -_- don't know why it is doing that, do i have to call it from the ccnode or something?